# WindowClosing method

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog, windowlistener

I have multiple custom dialogs and I wanted an easy way to specify the closing operation. To start with I was using the anonymous inner windowListener class and specifying the closing method that way for each dialog.

I thought it would be more efficient to create my own class and implement the WindowListener class and specify one window closing method for all dialogs.

So I did this and it works great.

```
    public class WindowWatcher implements WindowListener{

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Are you sure you wish to exit?");
         int Answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure want to exit?", "Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (Answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
      }

    }
```

Note: there are other implemented method in the class..

Anyhow the problem I'm running in to is when I click exit, then click no, then I attempt to proceed with a dialog and say click ok.. Nothing happens.

I understand this has something to do with the UNINITIALIZED_VALUE of the calling JOptionPane.

I need to see the calling optionPane to this UNINITIALIZED_VALUE.  I think??

something like:

```
        optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);
```

the code above assumes I have access to the optionPane however. However in my class 'WindowWatcher' class I don't have access to it.

Any ideas how I can do this ? Perhaps I can cast e.GetSource() as a JOptionPane..

Edit.

```
   ((JOptionPane)e.getSource()).setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);
```

the above didn't work. "JDialog cannot be cast as a JoptionPane"

Many Thanks!

Comment: JOptionPane has CANCEL too, please I miss goal

Comment: please you lost edit in Q body, review that if is important

Answer (score 4):

- please can you use this code example as your SSCCE,
- put there multiple JDialogs,
- add WindowListener
- modify code inside showOptionDialog()
- pass parent for JOptionPane
- start with showOptionDialog(...........)
- then I'll delete this post here

.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("DefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)");
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    public ClosingFrame() {
        File.add(Exit);
        MenuBar.add(File);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
        WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                /*int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(1);
                }*/
            }
        };
        JButton btn = new JButton("Show second JFrame");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClosingFrame cf = new ClosingFrame();
                JButton btn = new JButton("Show first JFrame");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
                frame1.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                frame1.setLocation(100, 400);
                frame1.pack();
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

> You have this 'ExitListener' which works well when a user click the
>   exit menu item but when I click the red x, it merely sets visible as
>   false. I don't see how this helps me at all in regards to Dialog or
>   JOptionPanes.. what windowListener to you want me to add? More
>   confused to be honest.

1. as I already asked to post an `SSCCE`
2. see methods `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE, EXIT_ON_CLOSE, ....);` in API

   - default value is `JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE`, displayed and used as lesson
   - this is separate and direct methods implemented in API,
   - `JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE` == `frame.setVisible(false);`
   - Swing GUI required to change to `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`, because hidded `JFrame` or `JDialog` dosn't equals that the current JVM is terminated, and live untill PC restarted or turn off, `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` to terminating current JVM as `System.exit(int);`
3. `WindowListener` is another  separate and direct methods implemented in API, how to manage that

   - block all setting for `DefaultCloseOperation`
   - will be executed only code inside `windowXxx( Xxx == methods in WindowListener)`
   - otherwise nothing happends
4. back to my code posted here

   - disable `frame.setVisible(false);` == `//frame.setVisible(false);`
   - and (next code line ) remove `/*` and `*/`, then works as is mentioned in a.m. points

Comment: I'm just going over your code. My dialogs and optionPanes have all been created in methods.. Should I make them variables of my class? Seems to make sense, then I can access them anywhere.

Comment: @ mKorbel, You have this 'ExitListener' which works well when a user click the exit menu item but when I click the red x, it merely sets visible as false. I don't see how this helps me at all in regards to Dialog or JOptionPanes.. what windowListener to you want me to add? More confused to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I may be a little late to the party, but for future reference:

note: this approach is somewhat unconventional and somewhat longer than the average method, but it works, so if it comes down to it, this is an acceptable solution.

What I like to do is skip the JOptionPane altogether and use a JDialog, Just construct the message and buttons in your class's constructor, then have an ActionListener ready to catch all buttons, and just in case, attach a WindowsListener to the dialog as well, that way you can catch all possible outcomes.

Assuming you're using your own class's frame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WindowCloseDialog implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

    private JDialog closeDialog;
    private JButton yesButton, noButton;

    WindowCloseDialog() {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Window Close Dialog Application");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.addWindowListener(this);//catch the window being closed
        ...
        closeDialog = new JDialog("Quit");
        closeDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        closeDialog.addWindowListener(this);//catch the dialog being closed
        JLabel closeLabel = new JLabel("Would you like to exit?");
        yesButton = new JButton("Yes");
        yesButton.addActionListener(this);//catch an answer of yes
        noButton = new JButton("No");
        noButton.addActionListener(this);//catch an answer of no
        //add your components to your closeDialog in whatever manner you fancy
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {
        if (w.getWindow().equals(myFrame)) {
            closeDialog.setVisible(true);
        } else if (w.getWindow().equals(closeDialog)) {
            closeDialog.setVisible(false);//no exit on dialog close
        }
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(yesButton)) {
            closeDialog.setVisible(false);
            myFrame.setVisible(false);
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(noButton)) {
            closeDialog.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

if you aren't using your own class's frame, then the same rules still apply, because if this is the case, the other class says `frame.addWindowListener(org.example.WindowWatcher);` so you would do exactly as my code entails, just leave out the part in which you build your own frame.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it would be more efficient to create my own class and implement the WindowListener class and specify one window closing method for all dialogs.

Good idea. I have created my own class for doing this. See [Closing An Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for my version.

Your posted code looks reasonable to me. Did you add a println() statement inside the if statement to see if the System.exit() method is invoked.

My solution is slightly different. It manages the `default close operation` of the frame for you. This value is used to determine what happens when you click on the close icon. By default it must be set to `do nothing`, in case the user cancels the close. If the user accepts the close then you need to set it do your desired property.

Comment: +1 for detailed descriptions, I still think there no diff betweens System.exit(0) and EXIT_ON_CLOSE for rest of Java (non_deamon)threads,